# Grails Custom Tests

Tags: grails

I'm trying to set up a custom test type in grails 2.3.7 and I'd like for it to run when specifically invoked but not with test-app. I've tried to follow http://ldaley.com/post/615966534/custom-grails-test as best I can, but this blog post is a bit out of date.

So far this works for test-app :regression

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.junit4.JUnit4GrailsTestType

// test-app :regression -echoOut

eventTestPhasesStart = { phasesToRun ->
    println("Hiiii " + phasesToRun)
    phasesToRun << "regression"
}


def testTypeName = "regression"
def testDirectory = "regression"
def regressionTestType = new JUnit4GrailsTestType(testTypeName, testDirectory)

regressionTests = [regressionTestType]
```

How can I modify this to not be invoked when invoking test-app with no arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the variables `args` and `argsMap` from the event (via the closure delegate `GantBinding`). So something like this should work:

```
eventTestPhasesStart = { phasesToRun ->
    if (!args.empty) {
        phasesToRun << "regression"
    }
}
```

Not 100% sure that it will work out of the box. Maybe there are other test options that show up in `args` which would break the simple `empty` condition.

Comment: Thanks for the binding tip, it was pretty helpful. I ended up using a lock file, which seems pretty clunky.